# QTcpSocket can't bind to right IP

Tags: c++, qt, bind, qtcpsocket

I am building a linux Qt5/C++ app which runs on a system with multiple NIC's (multihomed).  I need to force my outgoing TCP connection to use a specific NIC/IP.  I have tried the following code but netstat confirms that my app is still using the wrong local NIC/IP.

```
if (m_tcpSocket->bind(localaddress)) qDebug() << "Bind success";
m_tcpSocket->connectToHost(
            remoteaddress,
            remoteport,
            QTcpSocket::ReadWrite);
}
```

Am I calling this incorrectly?  I see "bind success" so I assume the call is right...but I can't explain why its not working

---

Update: I found this bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-29732

Is there a workaround?  I see setLocalAddress() in QAbstractSocket but I'm not sure it's the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed the cause is a bug in the Qt library, reported [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29732).  This bug  has existed since Qt 4.8 and we're at Qt 5.3 today.  Hard to believe such a significant bug isn't fixed (significant for any app using network)

Comment: Sorry for non-informative comment. It's a sad thing I've noticed since Digia have taken over Qt. They started care less about C++ and dedicate most resources to QML :(